# Unable to integrate RASA chatbot to Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot, rasa

I have created a new app on Facebook and set up messenger and added an existing page.
I have put access token, secret, and verify to credentials.yml file in RASA project.

Using `ngrok` I created a callback URL and added it to the Facebook callback URL section.

When I enter verify token (token id from messenger app), it shows either callback URL or verify token is not correct.  callback URL I got from `ngrok`.   https://XX20a228353.ngrok.io/webhooks/facebook/webhook

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: So what result do you get when you call your callback URL, together with the appropriate parameters, directly in your browser?

Comment: I get bad gateway ,server returned invalid response

Comment: Well then you need to debug on your end, and figure out why this happens.

Comment: So it means there is an issue at callback url setup

Comment: Is there possibility of router configuration issue for this

Comment: Reqeat the same test without the tunnel, and see what result that gives you.

Comment: Really strange, but for me, I had to add a "/" at the end of the Callback URL for it to be validated.

Answer (score 0):

Verify token seems to be incorrect.

This should be a simple text (eg rasa-bot) which you need to specify in rasa credentials.yml file as secret. Please refer Rasa documentation -> https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/connectors/facebook-messenger/

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify 4 things:

 **+ 1st thing**
 - need to be checked is in your **credential.yml**

```
facebook:
 verify: "MyBot"
 secret: "<Secret_key_from_facebook_app>"
 page-access-token: "<Access_token_you_got_from_facebook_developer>"
```

The `MyBot` is what you suppose to put in **Verify Token** box above.

**+ 2nd thing**

- to be check is you need to `run rasa` run and/or `rasa run actions` both at the same time if you have custom action

**+ 3rd thing to do**

- make sure in **endpoints.yml** you need to uncomment this

  action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"   #TODO: Change localhost baseURL to custom server URL that host action server

**+ 4th thing to check**

- Make sure  you use the port number from the `rasa run` command, by default it suppose to be `5005` so you can do `ngrok http 5005` and use the `https` one

Hope this help, let's me know if you still have any concern.